# How to pass variable data to mask function jquery

Tags: jquery, mask

I format contact numbers with this format:

```
$('#Phone').mask('(000) 000-0000');
$('#Cellphone').mask('(000) 000-0000');
$('#Fax').mask('(000) 000-0000');
```

But I want to change the phone number to

```
$('#Phone').mask('+1 (000) 000-0000');
```

with +1 as country code. But that would only for US. I have database table for company phone codes and able to retrieve each code. But is it possible for me to pass those country code in a variable inside the mask function, making the +1 dynamically change depending on the country selected?